# treat negation character as a function

Tags: haskell

I am trying to figure out how to make haskell happy with the following equation:

```
f = either id (-1)
```

it complains:

```
No instance for (Num (Int -> Int))
  arising from a use of syntactic negation
In the second argument of ‘either’, namely ‘(- 1)’
In the expression: either id (- 1)
In an equation for ‘f’: f = either id (- 1)
```

Do I have to resort to

```
f = either id (\x -> x-1)
```

or maybe there is a a type signature that will make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\x -> x - 1` as you suggest, or `subtract 1`. Prefix negation is a special case: `(-1)`, unlike `(1-)`, [doesn't become a section](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-300003.5).